# How to get list of objects inside Json object in android

Tags: android, json

I have one JSON that looks like below, in this JSON I have one object and inside this object, I have a list of other objects, so how to read the object list from the main object `foo` also the insider list is dynamic

this is my JSON

```
foo: {
    "foo1": {
        "end": 12,
        "start": 0
    },
    "foo2": {
        "end": 7,
        "start": 0
    },
    "foo3": {
        "end": 12,
        "start": 8
    },
    {
    ...
    },
    ....
}
```

Comment: You can use GSON to serialization/deserialization that json into an object  [link](https://github.com/google/gson)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the json to variable and then access the data using hierarchy.

```
var obj = {foo: {
"foo1": {
    "end": 12,
    "start": 0
},
"foo2": {
    "end": 7,
    "start": 0
},
"foo3": {
    "end": 12,
    "start": 8
}



 obj.foo.foo1 //This will show the obj foo1
 obj.foo //this will show the obj.foo
```